# Unable to upload object to GCP storage via spring boot rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

am getting the below error when i try to upload with rest api especially with spring boot
, i have used the code earlier i created to do the same with rest api but now its shows like this as well as i have enabled billing for the storage account. I can upload objects with other rest api services with express and python flask

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/pdf-split-ingestion/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart

{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"location" : "Authorization",
"locationType" : "header",
"message" : "The account for bucket "pdf-split-ingestion" has not enabled billing.",
"reason" : "accountDisabled"
} ],
"message" : "The account for bucket "pdf-split-ingestion" has not enabled billing."
}
Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class Controller {

@Autowired
private Repo repo;

String projectId = "spring-b-357511";
String bucketName = "pdf-split-ingestion";
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
@PostMapping("/upload-file")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile1(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file){
    String Name = file.getOriginalFilename();
    if (file.isEmpty()){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("File is missing in request");
    }

    try{
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        byte data[] = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, file.getOriginalFilename());
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
        storage.create(blobInfo,data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Model response = new Model();
    repo.save(response);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded Successfully");
```

}

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: WHat's your authentication mode? Did you change something?

Comment: I have changed the project and bucket name in the existing code that i have used before